# Creating Link Button from the code behind based on the returning Data from DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I need help with creating Link button dynamic wise, I'm populating data from the DB and based on the data that coming back I want to create on my page a link button can someone please help me with this...

***(I need to get rid of the Duplicate in the list below)**

My VB.NET Code:

```
 Dim RegionName As String = Nothing
        Dim RegionID As String = Nothing
        Dim output As String = Nothing

        For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows()
            RegionName = dr.Item("RegionName").ToString()
            RegionID = dr.Item("RegionID").ToString()

            '# Creating instance of LinkButton
            Dim lb As New LinkButton()
            lb = New LinkButton()
            lb.Text = RegionName '# LinkButton Text
            lb.ID = RegionID.ToString() '# LinkButton ID's
            lb.CommandArgument = RegionID.ToString() '# LinkButton CommandArgument
            lb.CommandName = RegionName '# LinkButton CommanName
            AddHandler lb.Click, AddressOf lb_Command '# Create Handler for it
            PlaceHolder.Controls.Add(lb)

            Dim lbl As New Label()
            lbl.Text = "<br>"
            PlaceHolder.Controls.Add(lbl)

        Next


Private Sub lb_Command(sender As Object, e As CommandEventArgs)
    Dim lnk As LinkButton = TryCast(sender, LinkButton)
    lblDynamicRegion.Text = e.CommandName
    '# Will display the which Linkbutton clicked
    If lnk.Font.Bold = True Then
        lnk.Font.Bold = False
        lnk.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue
    Else
        lnk.Font.Bold = True
        lnk.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green
    End If

End Sub
```

The list from the DB that I want to create Link Button for:

```
SouthEast (MD, NC, FL)
MidWest
SouthEast (MD, NC, FL)
SouthEast (MD, NC, FL)
NorthWest
San Diego
Los Angeles
MidWest
SouthEast (MD, NC, FL)
NorthEast (NY, CT)
SouthEast (MD, NC, FL)
Los Angeles
NorthWest
Centro Properties Group
Los Angeles
Los Angeles
MidWest
MidWest
NorthWest
NorthEast (NY, CT)
MidWest
MidWest
MidWest
San Diego
Demo
MidWest
Los Angeles
NorthEast (NY, CT)
NorthWest
Centro Properties Group
San Diego
San Diego
SouthEast (MD, NC, FL)
San Diego
NorthWest
MidWest
Los Angeles
San Diego
San Diego
Los Angeles
Centro Properties Group
NorthWest
Los Angeles
SouthEast (MD, NC, FL)
NorthWest
MidWest
NorthEast (NY, CT)
NorthWest
SouthEast (MD, NC, FL)
MidWest
Los Angeles
NorthEast (NY, CT)
San Diego
Los Angeles
NorthWest
NorthWest
Los Angeles
Centro Properties Group
SouthEast (MD, NC, FL)
SouthEast (MD, NC, FL)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data were sorted, it would be easier.  As it stands, to de-duplicate the results, you'll have to 'remember' each unique value you've seen.  This assumes that the text of the Region is exactly the same for duplicated items.  Alternately, you could use the RegionID.

Also, when you declare an object with the new keyword, it creates an instance of the object, so you don't need to instantiate the object later.  That's why I removed the lb = New LinkButton() statement.

```
        Dim RegionName As String = Nothing
        Dim RegionID As String = Nothing
        Dim output As String = Nothing
        Dim Regions as New System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollction()

        For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows()
            RegionName = dr.Item("RegionName").ToString()
            If Not Regions.Contains(RegionName) Then
               Regions.Add(RegionName)
               RegionID = dr.Item("RegionID").ToString()

               '# Creating instance of LinkButton
               Dim lb As New LinkButton()
               lb.Text = RegionName '# LinkButton Text
               lb.ID = RegionID.ToString() '# LinkButton ID's
               lb.CommandArgument = RegionID.ToString() '# LinkButton CommandArgument
               lb.CommandName = RegionName '# LinkButton CommanName
               AddHandler lb.Click, AddressOf lb_Command '# Create Handler for it
               PlaceHolder.Controls.Add(lb)

               Dim lbl As New Label()
               lbl.Text = "<br>"
               PlaceHolder.Controls.Add(lbl)
           End If

        Next


Private Sub lb_Command(sender As Object, e As CommandEventArgs)
    Dim lnk As LinkButton = TryCast(sender, LinkButton)
    lblDynamicRegion.Text = e.CommandName
    '# Will display the which Linkbutton clicked
    If lnk.Font.Bold = True Then
        lnk.Font.Bold = False
        lnk.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue
    Else
        lnk.Font.Bold = True
        lnk.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green
    End If

End Sub
```